# Error in the newsletter. How to deal with?

Tags: errors, customer-support, customer-experience

We sent our monthly newsletter to our users with an error inside.
Only 3 for 1000 customers complained about that.

We can send a corrected version to all the customers or just those who complained. Our goal is to have the best customer experience.

What's the best attitude ?

Comment: It will probably depend a lot on the error. Is it a typo or is it a misprint of a sale price that could cost you thousands of dollars?

Comment: Just data report with some errors... no big consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you should always send it all the customers. Those who didn't complain doesn't mean they never noticed it, they are just avoiding the hassle of complaining or just ignoring it. It's always a nice gesture to send the correct version with a little note of apology in the previous one, or maybe offer them some kind of compensation or perk, if it's something paid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without providing specifics the answer would depends. If it would greatly impact the business or some sort then yes you have to re-send it to all and rectify whenever you can. Now if its just cosmetics or some technical incompatibilities with low to no impact to business then just respond to the ones who complained. Also, good practice is to have an online version that you could easily rectify.